# How to get to the post on certain date in FB with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to read previous posts of a FB page. I used Selenium to scroll down the page but the page stopped loading and there was no response. How to efficiently get to the posts on a certain date, say, 1-1-2017?

I tried:

```
for j in range(10000):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100000)")
```

The FB Page hanged before getting to the posts I want. I tried to find the path of loading more pages using xpath. Then, I may load more posts every time but I cannot do it.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: you want to stick to selenium ?? if it's not necessary use graph api of facebook. just a thought.

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use _Facebook API_ instead.